# Liquibase - checkSum of JSON file

Tags: database, spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to update a row with a specific 'CODE' column. But I'm dealing with this issue: I cannot compute the checkSum of the file in the PreConditions tag in myCheckSum so I have to upload each time new whole JSON file each.

I would consider something like this as a solution, but with no result.

```
<changeSet author="name" id="changeset_id">
  <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <fileExists path="path/to/my/file" />
    <fileCheckSum path="path/to/my/file.json" />
  </preConditions>
  
    <!-- My additional commands -->
   <update tableName="WF_SCENARIO">
            <column name="DATA" valueClobFile="path/to/my/file.json"/>
            <where>CODE = 'SOME_CODE'</where>
   </update>
</changeSet>
```

Has someone any idea how I can do this updates of JSON file, I'm trying to update into DB column?

Thank you

Comment: I am using DatabaseChangeLog with schema xsd xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.5.xsd

Comment: what is the problem? do you want to update the blob only when there is change or do you want to update it each time? If each time, consider [runAlways](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/run-always.html)

Comment: Yes, I want update blob only when JSON is changes. But business logic doesn't allow me to runAlways

Comment: I don't think this is possible with liquibase out of the box. However you can implement your [custom change](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/custom-change.html) for that